# Trying to group mysql events with matching dates

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a simple event form, which displays the date of the event and any events with the same date underneath.e.g. matching date events are listed underneath the same date. Currently it is displaying each insert individually rather than grouping by date.

```php
$readquery  = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE id=$userid GROUP BY event_date";
$readresult = $link->query($readquery);
if (!$readresult) {
    echo $link->error;
}
```

Above is the data being called from the SQL table.

```php
<?php
while ($row = $readresult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $userid = $row["id"];
    $event_date = $row["event_date"];
    $event_item = $row["event_item"];
    echo "
    <br>
    <div class='card border border-dark'>
        <b> $event_date</b>
        <div class='card-body' style='background-color:#6497ED;'>
            <div class='card border-dark mb-3 mx-auto' style='max-width: 18rem;'>
                <div class='card-body text-dark'>
                    <h5 class='card-title text-center'>$event_item</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
}
```

above is trying to display this in a card. Any help would be great!

Comment: This is not an sql question, this is a display question. SQL's group by statement is for creating aggregates, i.e. determining the number of events on a date. You just need sorting in sql, everything else is done in php/html/css.

Answer (score 0):

You say `"Currently it is displaying each insert individually rather than grouping by date."` and that is because you do not use any aggregator function like `(COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG)` with this work you say to your query to group your result and I think use the aggregator function in SQL will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: No, aggregate functions won’t help, because they _don’t_ want to aggregate multiple records into a single one, they want to display all of them.

Comment: But he/she said "Currently it is displaying each insert individually rather than grouping by date."

Comment: Sorry, i worded it wrong, it is displaying under each of the event dates and event items but i need the event date and then underneath all the event items that match that date.